# Do Prefix Notation with Cup

Tags: java, parsing, flex-lexer, cup

I create this code:

```
 import java_cup.runtime.*;


terminal MAS,MENOS,POR,DIV,AP,CP,MINUS;
terminal String NUMERO,IDENT;
non terminal A;

precedence left  MAS,MENOS;
precedence left POR,DIV;
precedence left AP,CP;
precedence left MINUS;



A ::= A:a1 MAS {:System.out.print("+ ");:} A:a2 {:System.out.print(a1+""+a2+" ");RESULT = "";:} 
    | A:a1 MENOS {:System.out.print("- ");:} A:a2 {:System.out.print(a1+""+a2+" ");RESULT = "";:} 
    | A:a1 POR {:System.out.print("* ");:} A:a2 {:System.out.print(a1+""+a2+" ");RESULT = "";:} 
    | A:a1 DIV {:System.out.print("/ ");:} A:a2 {:System.out.print(a1+""+a2+" ");RESULT = "";:} 
    | AP {:System.out.print("");:} A:a1 CP {:System.out.print("");RESULT = "";:}
    | NUMERO:n1 {:RESULT = n1+" ";:}
    | IDENT:i1 {:RESULT = i1+" ";:}
    | MENOS  A:a1
    %prec MINUS;
```

The solution to this expression: alfa + beta * gamma +77 is + + alfa * beta gamma 77 but the program doesnt show the correct solution,anyone can help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are printing the intermediate value of operators when you should be returning it as `RESULT` as you do with identifiers and numbers. You should only print the string when you have finished parsing the entire expression. (You might use a unit production for that.)

Comment: Thanks now it works, one more question, its posible to debug cup to see the list of the production thats follow ?

Comment: @ivan: i don't know much about CUP's debugging features, sorry. But in any case, that's a completely different question which should be asked as such.